# Notation for optional addition sign

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

Is there a way to notate an optional addition? I'm thinking of something similar to the plus-minus sign $\pm$. For reference, I have two angles $\theta$ and $\theta+\pi/2$ and want to include them both in one line.

Hopefully, there is something simpler than $\theta + \pi/4 \pm \pi/4$.

Comment: I don't think there is any standard notation for this. Why not just say "for $\alpha = \theta$ and $\alpha = \theta + \pi/2$ we have $... \alpha ...$"?

Comment: I see. I'm solving an equation where the angles are two roots, but only one is valid. I'm trying to write it out compactly, but it might not be possible to do what I want.

Comment: You have options like $\alpha\in\{\theta,\theta+\pi/2\}$ and $\alpha=\theta+\{0,\pi/2\}$ as well, but the more terse your method means that confusion is more likely.

Comment: @abiessu: I don't think $\alpha = \theta + \{0, \pi/2\}$ would be widely understood.

Comment: Honestly, $\alpha = \theta +  \{ 0,\pi/2 \}$ is what I'm looking for, though it is a stretch to use it in many settings.

Comment: @robarthan: agreed, it would have to be a notation that is introduced, but it does have some similarities to interval arithmetic which seem promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest $\alpha = \theta + \epsilon\cdot \pi/2$ for $\epsilon \in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: This is a good approach to the described idea.